# cancel upload after user selects file in rich:upload

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

Is there any possibility to cancel file upload after user selects the file in the richfaces `rich:fileUpload` control?

My use case is as follows:

1. User selects the file.
2. I validate the filename on client side before upload. File mask is a bit sophisticated so using `acceptedTypes` is not enough.
3. If validation is OK then the file is uploaded, otherwise an
   error message is displayed (via alert() or preferably rich:messages)

I have been trying to achieve this with a js function in `onfilesubmit` or `onfileselect` returning `false` to cancel the event, but this didn't work.

As a workaround I may validate the file name in the upload listener but the listener code is executed only after the file is uploaded. And as the uploaded files can be big (even up to a few hundred MBs or a few GBs) this would be a huge usability drawback.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the immediate upload then the easiest approach is to overwrite the `RichFaces.ui.FileUpload.prototype.__accept` method with your validation, the method takes the filename and returns true/false.

Comment: Hi Makhiel, I am having exatly the same issue i.e. to validate the name and not to allow upload if file name does not match criteria. How could I override .__accept the method you mentioned. how do I receive the file name in this method? how to call this method before upload event? How do I include this method in actual page? My page is an xtml page and using rich fileUpload.

Comment: @Vikky it's JavaScript, if you don't know how to do any of that you need to learn the basics, you can start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)